# underfined function error in go :jmpToFunctionValue

Tags: go, goland

While running main.go getting this error in monkey file and function is given below.

## bou.ke/monkey

../go/pkg/mod/bou.ke/monkey@v1.0.2/replace.go:24:14: undefined: jmpToFunctionValue

Anyone help me with that?

Comment: The `jmpToFunctionValue` is not implemented for your OS or architecture. I would not recommend using an unsupported, unmaintained library to try and monkey patch the executable at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

I also face this error while using mac M1.

could you check the goarch var in `go env`? if you got `arm64`, you need to change it to `amd64` using this command

```
 go env -w GOARCH=amd64
```

it works for me